# How do I calculate the date : one year from the creation with a DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Subscription model with a `created` DateTimeField. The Subscriptions last one year from the date it was created. I also have a `expired` field. Not 100% sure if I want to have it as a DateTimeField() or a Boolean yet. I digress. What I want to be able to do is basically check/ keep track of when a Subscription will expire.

If anyone could offer any insight how to do this I'd be very greatful.

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expired = models.DateTimeField()

    def expiration(self):
         date = created + datetime.timedelta(365).isoformat()
         return self(expired=date)
```

error: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'isoformat'

Comment: What is happening when you try the current code? Are you getting an exception, bad data or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods:

## updated

because you cannot use self.created in the setting of expired.

### models.py

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expired = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.expired = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(365) # original answer used this line: self.created + datetime.timedelta(365).isoformat()
        super(Subscription, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Comment: Why can't the OP use `self.created`? The problem in his original code was that the was using `created` *instead* of `self.created`, which is undefined. Additionally, your code here will reset the expiration for another full year each time the model is saved, which almost assuredly not what the OP wants.

Comment: What if 365 days spans a leap day?

Answer (score 1):

Your `date` calculation is calling `isoformat` on the `timedelta` instance you are creating, which I suspect is where your error is coming from.

I think you just need some parentheses (and `self`):

```
date = (self.created + datetime.timedelta(365)).isoformat()
```

Comment: What if 365 days spans a leap day?

Comment: Well, personally I'd just ignore leap days, since the expiration date probably doesn't need to be exactly a full year from the start of the subscription (365 days is probably good enough). If it was determined to be important, @karthirkr's suggestion of using the `relativedelta` class from the [`dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to stick with `expired` being a `DateTimeField` on the model, then what you really want to do is override `clean`

```
def clean(self):
    if self.expired is None:
        self.expired = self.created + timedelta(days=365)
    return super(Subscription, self).clean()
```

Comment: What if 365 days spans a leap day?

Comment: I was using the user's current code. Perhaps the OP doesn't care if there's a leap day. It was not the focus of the question, and he didn't provide enough detail to make a determination that it *should* be done a different way.